# jQuery+ PHP adding new attributes to elements with specific value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to create a function that will add an attribute to elements that have an attribute with specific values.

$index have values 0-10, Code is working to this point: var element = $("a[data-slide-index*='"i"']");

Firebug gives me:

> Blockquote 
>   SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Rest looks like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

           jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

                for(var i=0; i<parseInt(<?php echo json_encode($index); ?>);i++){

                  var hoverAtt = "onHover"+i+"()";
                   var element = $("a[data-slide-index*='"+ i +"']");


                 element.next().attr("onmouseover", function(){
                       return hoverAtt;

                   });

                   }
           })
            </script>
```

There is jFidle example for $index=6:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fuh9P/

Edit: I changed concatenation as Sjoerd suggested but still doesn't work.

Comment: JsFiddle won't work for the PHP statement right?

Comment: You could do a JsFiddle with some sample data your app has outputted though.

Comment: Be aware that `return hoverAtt` will return the string "onHover123()", it will not call the function.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is because you concatenate strings the wrong way. You have this:

```
var element = $("a[data-slide-index*='"i"']");
```

Within the `$()` you try to concatenate three parts, like this:

```
"a"i"b"
```

Instead, you should use something like this:

```
"a" + i + "b"
var element = $("a[data-slide-index*='" + i + "']");
```